# Java takes too long time to initialize large OpenType fonts

Tags: java, fonts

I must use Noto Sans CJK font in my application.
But when I call the method below It takes 10 seconds to initialize.

```
Font font = //Noto Sans CJK font
JComponent.getFontMetrics(An instance of Noto Sans CJK font);
```

Can I fix this delay problem? The code can be complicated if the method can help fixing this problem(Like implementing FontMetrics, I don't know how).

Please don't recommend me convert otf font to ttf font. I couldn't convert it because font tool said it's alphabetic font and coundn't even load unicode glyphs. Also I have to use another otf font in application. And I won't use already converted version.

- If you can fix this issue with Java code, I wanna use this method.
- If any unicode otf fonts can be converted to ttf, I'll use that tool(BUT MUST BE FREE, NO TRIAL. FULL FREE). Please tell me how to convert otf to ttf. I tried website and fontforge. Both returned 7KB font even this font is 7MB.

I'm not good at English. Sorry.

Comment: What Java version are you on?

Comment: I'm on Java 1.8.0_192. I can't use newer versions because I'm targetting 32-bit system. Of cource I don't like 32-bit too,

Comment: Can you show a [mcve]? Not just to help us, but also to help you.

Comment: Font baseFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/Noto.otf"));
            Font noto = baseFont.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 10);
            System.out.println(noto);

Comment: Which is similar to my second example (except in this snippet you don't gather the metrics). **a)** What hardware spec do you have (CPU, RAM, HDD/SDD, OS)? **b)** From where did you get the `Noto.otf`? Have you tried with the version I mention in my examples? If so, could you notice a difference?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should provide step by step instructions to reproduce your issue.

I did following on my system.

- install font file `NotoSansCJKjp-Regular.otf` from [NotoSansCJKjp-hinted.zip](https://noto-website-2.storage.googleapis.com/pkgs/NotoSansCJKjp-hinted.zip)
- compile the example code

  ```
  $ javac NotoFont.java
  ```
- run the compiled code

  ```
  $ time java NotoFont
  ```

The execution takes less than a second on my system.

output of the above run

```
java.awt.Font[family=Noto Sans CJK JP Regular,name=Noto Sans CJK JP Regular,style=plain,size=10]

real    0m0.522s
user    0m0.565s
sys     0m0.056s
```

**NotoFont.java**

```
import java.awt.Font;
class NotoFont {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Font noto = new Font("Noto Sans CJK JP Regular", Font.PLAIN, 10);
        System.out.println(noto);
    }
}
```

**edit** An example to read the font file from inside the Jar. The font is not installed on the system.

Assume following structure.

```
build/fonts/NotoSansCJKjp-Regular.otf
dist/
NotoFont.java
```

**NotoFont.java**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.swing.*;
class NotoFont {
    private void run() throws FontFormatException, IOException {
        try (InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/fonts/NotoSansCJKjp-Regular.otf")) {
            Font baseFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, is);
            Font noto = baseFont.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 10);
            System.out.println(noto);
            FontMetrics metrics = new JPanel().getFontMetrics(noto);
            System.out.println(metrics);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FontFormatException, IOException {
        new NotoFont().run();
    }
}
```

- compile the code

  ```
  $ javac -d build/ NotoFont.java
  ```
- create the Jar

  ```
  $ jar cf dist/notofont.jar -C build/ .
  ```
- check the Jar content

  ```
  $ cd dist/
  $ jar tf notofont.jar
  META-INF/
  META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
  NotoFont.class
  fonts/
  fonts/NotoSansCJKjp-Regular.otf
  ```
- run the code

  ```
  $ time java -cp notofont.jar NotoFont
  ```

output of above run

```
java.awt.Font[family=Noto Sans CJK JP Regular,name=Noto Sans CJK JP Regular,style=plain,size=10]
sun.font.FontDesignMetrics[font=java.awt.Font[family=Noto Sans CJK JP Regular,name=Noto Sans CJK JP Regular,style=plain,size=10]ascent=9, descent=3, height=12]
real 3.02
user 2.11
sys 0.84
```

Comment: otf file is resource file and inside jar file. I must use Font.createFont to get Font instance from InputStream. And this delay occured while getting FontMetrics with JComponent.getFontMetrics method

Comment: @dhkim0800 I added another example. To read the font from the Jar and to print the font metrics. Now it takes around 3 secs. As I said you should provide more information. e.g a snippet which can be used to reproduce your issue, about your system, ...

Comment: I'm windows user. I don't have time command. I'll try your code with system.currentTimeMillis()